# Search results error on single server setup

Tags: configuration, indexing, lucene

We have a client site that is spread across 2 cd's and 1 cm which we have migrated to a single server instance for QA purposes.

The production site has a public address for the cd's and a private address for the cm server which we have simulated on the QA environment.  Basically 2 bindings point to the same Sitecore.

We seem to be having an issue with search.  If we browse to the site using the binding that was used for the CM server, our search works fine, however when we search on the site that uses the CD binding we get an exception.

This is a simple null exception in the code, but i am curious as to why the search runs ok using the CM binding but errors using CD binding.

Perhaps a config setting?

Apologies if this is a bit vague

Comment: Richard I think your going to need to share some more details with us such as your Sitecore version, if your using Solr or Lucene etc and also ideally the search config from your CD and CA servers with us in order for us to help you properly with this.

Comment: Do you have separate sites defined for these two bindings in your config?

Comment: Aren't you trying to search in master index in code? In CD server this will be disabled together with access to master db. If you followed security hardening. Isn't this your case? Please specify Sitecore version and search engine.